# Powershell to split Display name and use it to populate First Last name

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Need some help with my code. I have users in OU, they have Display Name attribute but First/Last name are empty. I am trying to populate them using powershell. here is what i got so far:

```
get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=FTE,OU=GLS,OU=Staff,DC=domain,DC=com’ | % {$_.name –split " "}
```

This gives me the output for John Doe as

John
Doe

now i am trying to set these values using this, but it fails:

```
$SplitName = $_.name –split " "

get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=FTE,OU=GLS,OU=Staff,DC=domain,DC=com’ | % {Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -GivenName $SplitName[0] -Surname $SplitName[1]}
```

I think i am not using the split correctly, but I am not sure.

Comment: Is your second code sample part of something bigger? `$_` can't be used by itself, it has to be used in the context of the execution pipeline.

Comment: @Poorkenny it is, % is an alias for `Foreach-Object` so that looks fine...

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @AustinFrench I know that ;) Although the first line of the second sample seems to be using `$_` outside of any loop or pipeline... Hence the question.

Comment: @Poorkenny I get what you mean now!

Comment: Please read TheMadTechnician's note on the accepted answer and follow it up with [this blog post](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). Rather than make *assumptions* about first and last names, get them from your company's system of record for employee names (HR database, perhaps?) and use that. This way, names as seen in AD will match peoples' preferences about how their names are presented elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without AD with me, I don't see why this wouldn't work:

```
get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=FTE,OU=GLS,OU=Staff,DC=domain,DC=com’ | % {
       $splitName = $_.name –split " "
       Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -GivenName $SplitName[0] -Surname $SplitName[1]
    }
```

Comment: This works great, right up to where you have somebody with a name like "Ann Marie Johnston", and it declares her first name to be Ann, and her last name to be Marie, when it should be Ann Marie for the first name, and Johnston as the last name.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician you are right, it absolutely won't pass that test, or if Marie were a middle name, or if the is James Richards III... Where Richards is the last name.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a range as well can combine the mid last into one last name. like John Van Smith would have $var[1..-1] # VanSmith.

```
PS> Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'OU=FTE,OU=GLS,OU=Staff,DC=domain,DC=com' -Filter * | % {
     $dnSplit = $_.Name -split " "; Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -GivenName $dnSplit[0] -Surname $($dnSplit[1..-1] -join "")
}
```